# Search method on Word's paragraph object not working

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js

I have a `paragraphsArray` of paragraph objects. I have `keywordRanges` of indexes of some paragraphs and keywords. I am trying to iterate over keywordRanges and get the RangeObject of the keyword from the paragraph object.

But the code fails after first iteration with this error:
`PropertyNotLoaded: The property 'items' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.`

Code for reference:

```
var myObject = {
  "2":{
    "keywords":["the","which","eye"]
  },
  "4":{
    "keywords":["lorem","ipsum"]
  },
  "9":{
    "keywords":["hellow","world","foo","bar"]
  }
},
paragraphsArray = [],
keywordRanges = []

Word.run((context) => {

  // Create a proxy object for the document body.
  var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs

  // Queue a commmand to get the OOXML contents of the body.
  context.load(paragraphs, 'text, font, style');

  // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
  // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
  return context.sync()
  .then(() => {
    // push paragraph range objects to an array
    for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++) {
      paragraphsArray.push(paragraphs.items[i]) 
    }

    $.each(myObject, (key, value) => {
      $.each(value.keywords, (idx, keyword) => {
        // add the paragraph range object for the corresponding keyword to an array
        var obj = {range:paragraphsArray[key], keyword:keyword}
        keywordRanges.push(obj);
      })
    })
  })
  .then(()=>{
    if(keywordRanges.length > 0){
       $.each(keywordRanges, (idx, obj) =>{

        // search keyword in the paragraph range object
        // obj.range is Paragraph Range object
        var searchKeywordResults = obj.range.search(obj.keyword, { matchWholeWord: true})
        context.load(searchKeywordResults, 'text, font')

        return context.sync().then(() => {
          for (var i = 0; i < searchKeywordResults.items.length; i++) {
            console.log(searchKeywordResults.items[i])
          }
        })
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Trying to reproduce with your code I get error "Unable to get property 'search' of undefined or null reference" which kind of matches your question title but does not match the error you mention in your question. Could you please clarify the title and/or error description, and also what do you mean by "after first iteration".

Comment: Working with this a little bit more. I can see a couple of problems that might be relevant
1. You define the obj variable with `var obj = {range:paragraphsArray[key], keyword:keyword}, so the property you call "range" is actually a Word.Paragraph object, not a Word.Range object. 2. You call context.sync inside an each loop. This is not a good practice. Try adding each searchKeywordResults to an array in your loop. Then outside the loop, context.load() the entire array.

Comment: 3. That same context.sync is followed by a then(), which means you have a new Promise chain with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @RickKirkham Point 2 - `context.load()` didn't work on arrays, had to load each searchKeywordResult individually followed immediately by `context.sync()`. 

Point 3 - This was the actual issue. Fixed it by using ES6 `async/await` feature. The search is still very slow, working on the optimization. Could you give some inputs?

Comment: I'll make point 3 an "answer". For the performance issue, I think you should start a new question, since it is really a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have a context.sync in a loop that is followed by a then(), which means you have a new Promise chain with each iteration of the loop. All the promises have to be resolved before the Word.run() ends.